# NSMenuItem custom view drawRect not always called

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsmenu

I'm using a custom view for NSMenu items so I can control the background colour via `isHighlighted`.

The issue is, if you use a combination of mouse and keyboard to navigate the menu, it's possible to have two items selected at once. This is because `drawRect` isn't being called on some items to dehighlight them

Has anyone else run into this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NSMenuItems should be created using:

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:@selector(menuItemSelected:) keyEquivalent:@""];
```

where the selector menuItemSelected: is a valid method. isHighlighted won't be toggled if a valid action selector is not provided

Answer (score 0):

Conform `NSMenuDelegate` and implement following function like this:

```
func menu(_ menu: NSMenu, willHighlight item: NSMenuItem?) {
    for item in menu.items.compactMap({ return $0.isHighlighted ? $0 : nil }) {
        item.view?.needsDisplay = true
    }
}
```